# jQuery hover shows and hide my content

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I'm trying to show some content when I hover over an image... and hide it again after that. My problem is that, when I hover over the image the content is shown (but not instantly), and the content starts to hide and show while I'm over the image. When I leave the image, my content remains hidden.

This is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.opciones_imagen').hide();

   $('#id_imagen_1').hover(function(){
            $('.opciones_imagen').show();
        }, function(){
            $('.opciones_imagen').hide();
        });

});
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<div class="img1">

        {{ HTML::image(Session::get('url_imagen_1'), '', array( 'width' => '100%', 'id' => 'id_imagen_1', 'class' => 'show_imagen1' )) }}
        <div class="show_imagen_opciones1 opciones_imagen">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
            </button>               
                <a href="" class="cambiar_imagen1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nuevaImagen1"> Cambiar imagen</a>
                {{ link_to_route('session.eliminar', 'Eliminar', 'url_imagen_1', array('class' => 'eliminar_imagen1 btn btn-danger'))}}
        </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

I've tried it with CSS like this:

```
.opciones_imagen{
    display: none;
}

.show_imagen1:hover .opciones_imagen{
    display : block;
}
```

But I don't have any response. I'm doing something wrong... :(

Comment: use css, not js for this.

Comment: the css must look like this: `.show_imagen1:hover, .opciones_imagen:hover`.

Comment: could you edit your answer to see what you mean... I think I've tried every option... (obviously there is one more...)

Answer (score 0):

As Dementic stated in the comments, use CSS for this task:

```
.opciones_imagen {
    display: none;
}
.opciones_imagen:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't work. I've also tried the code I've pasted in my edited answer... but I don't have any result.